# Best symbol table choice java

Tags: java, symbol-table

I have a large txt file (~750MB) where every line contains a password and the time taken to generate that password. I need to create a symbol table so if a user inputs a possible password, I can quickly access the corresponding time it took to generate that password.

What would be a good symbol table implementation to minimize this lookup time?

Comment: Use the password itself as the key and locate the corresponding line in the file to retrieve the time taken. No need to complicate the implementation.

Comment: Is the file sorted ?

Comment: The file is not sorted although each "time" is going to be greater than the time taken on the line before it.